# string encryption with Keccak256 in app Flutter

Tags: flutter, keccak, pointycastle

we are making an app to make transactions in the polygon BlockChain.

We need to encrypt a String with Kecca256 encryption, which is what Poligon receives.

Could someone help me how to encrypt a String with that Protocol

Comment: There's an implementation here: https://pub.dev/packages/pointycastle

Comment: Yes, I was reviewing that, but I couldn't manage to implement it, maybe you have more knowledge about it, and can you help me?

Comment: Keccak-255 is a hash, not encryption (as far I know). Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide and then try to be more specific

Comment: Show what you tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you know, a hash takes in bytes and emits bytes. So, to hash a string, you need to convert it first to bytes using a character encoding - perhaps ASCII or UTF8.

To use `pointycastle` import the package, construct the right digest and process the bytes.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:pointycastle/export.dart';

void main() {
  final digest = KeccakDigest(256);
  final hash = digest.process(ascii.encode('input'));
  print(hash);
}
```